# Is there a good reason why the Maximum property of ScrollBar can only be reached programmatically?

Tags: .net, winforms, scrollbar

Intuitively one would assume that the [`Minimum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.minimum.aspx) and `Maximum` properties of [ScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2htecew.aspx) can be used to control its range accessible by the user, but [`Maximum`'s MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.maximum.aspx#remarksToggle) states:

> You might consider adjusting the
>   `Maximum` property dynamically to match
>   the size of the scroll bar's parent in
>   proportion to pixel size or to the
>   number of rows or lines displayed.
>
> The maximum value can only be reached
>   programmatically. The value of a
>   scroll bar cannot reach its maximum
>   value through user interaction at run
>   time. The maximum value that can be
>   reached through user interaction is
>   equal to 1 plus the `Maximum` property
>   value minus the [`LargeChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.largechange.aspx)
>   property value. If necessary, you can
>   set the `Maximum` property to the size
>   of the object -1 to account for the
>   term of 1.

Can you explain why this is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is because the value of the scroll bar refers to the *start* of the range displayed by the scrollable area. So if the user were allowed to scroll to its maximum value via user interaction, then they would be able to scroll the content off the top of the control.

Often times I've seen applications that do allow you to scroll until the end of the content passes the top of the scrolling region. (Leaving a blank region visible.) But intuitively you'd expect that the scroll bar would stop you once the you've reached the bottom of the scrollable region.

I know I just sound like a raving lunatic. Hopefully it made some sense.

Comment: +1 This doesn't sound lunatical to me at all. In fact, it's exactly the same explanation that I would have given. The iPhone is the most famous example of a UI that allows the user to scroll *past* the content area. But this type of interface is still alien in desktop applications, where touch screens don't rule the roost.